# Installing Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common to Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, scripting, installation

simply I cannot do it, I get the error screenshot shown below all the time.

Could someone tell me what I do wrong?

- NuPackage Manager 3.3.0
- I did "Install-Package Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common" on Console, still not installing and the same errors.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you are seeing indicates that the latest version of `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common` is not compatible with the .NET target framework for your project which is .NET Framework 4.5.2. You can set it to .Net Framework 4.6 by right clicking on the project -> Properties -> Application Tab and set Target Framework to `.NET Framework 4.6` and you should be able to install the latest `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common` package.
[image]

Alternatively, if you want to continue to run your project using 4.5.2 framework, try this older version of the package
`Install-Package Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common -Version 1.3.2`